# Trying to connect to wwwroot and get a image

Tags: image, file, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp-net-core-spa-services

I work in aspnet core mvc technology,
I manage to add an image, it does go to wwwroot, but the image does not display well in the browser
Example: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKCbb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpxu0.png)

My Controller:

```
 [HttpPost,ActionName("CreateAnimal")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAnimal([FromForm] CreateAnimalViewModel model)
    {
        string wwwPath = _Environment.WebRootPath;
        string contentPath = _Environment.ContentRootPath;
        ModelState.Clear();
        model.Animal!.Category = _context.Categories.Where(c => c.CategoryId == model.Animal.CategoryId).FirstOrDefault()!;
        var path = Path.Combine(wwwPath, "Images", model.Photo!.FileName);
        if (model.Photo.Length > 0)
        {
            using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            await model.Photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        model.Animal.PhotoUrl = path;
        _context.Add(model.Animal);
        
        if (TryValidateModel(model))
        {

            _context.Add(model.Animal!);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Manager));
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name");
        return View();
    }
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PetShop.Data.Models.Animal>
<table id="Table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhotoUrl)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BirthDate)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)</th>
        <th>Edit Animel</th>
        <th>Delete Animel</th>
```

@foreach (var item in Model!) {

```
           <img class="Images" src="~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhotoUrl)">
       </td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryId)</td>
     
           <a asp-action="EditAnimel" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">
           <input type="submit" value="Edit">
           </a>
   
           <a asp-action="DeleteAnimel" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">
           <input type="submit" value="Delete">
           </a>
```

}

Comment: path issue... you've got a local file path in there... should be something like "localhost/images/your_file.png"?  (I use: AppContext.BaseDirectory... which is the directory where core runs, then add from there... then I use another controller to serve up files for download. ex: dl_file?id=file_id )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

ProductController.cs:

```
   [Route("product")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;

        public ProductController(IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment)
        {
            webHostEnvironment = _webHostEnvironment;
        }

        [Route("")]
        [Route("index")]
        [Route("~/")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
                return View("Index", new Product());
        }
        [Route("save")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Save(Product product, IFormFile photo)
        {
            if (photo == null || photo.Length == 0)
            {
                return Content("File not selected");
            }
            else
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(this.webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", photo.FileName);
                var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                product.Photo = photo.FileName;
            }
            ViewBag.product = product;

          

                return View("Success");
        }

    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model SingleFile.Models.Product

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form asp-controller="product" asp-action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="Price" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Photo</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="photo" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Success.cshtml:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Success</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Product Info</h3>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.product.Id</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.product.Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>@ViewBag.product.Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Photo</td>
            <td><img src="~/images/@ViewBag.product.Photo" width="120" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Product

```
 public class Product
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: It does not work for me
I think this line in view is my problem
src = "~/Images/@Html.DisplayFor (modelItem => item.PhotoUrl)"

Comment: Try to use <img src="~/Images/@item.PhotoUrl" width="120" asp-append-version="true"/>

Comment: I tried what you said it also does not work it is worse because even pictures that already exist it also does not show.

Comment: It gives me the full path and not what wwwroot @Qing Guo


C: \ Users \ danie \ OneDrive \ Desktop \ Projectss \ PetShop \ PetShop.Client \ wwwroot \ Images \ 6.png

Comment: Do you mean you can show the picture?

Comment: I can not see the image because I get the full path

Comment: For example: an image I already have in wwwroot so I get it like this:
HumiRabbit.jpg
But that I add it gives me a full path

Comment: Because you code' model.Animal.PhotoUrl = path; 'So you get full path. If you want the photo name , you should use 'model.Animal.PhotoUrl = PhotoUrl.FileName;'  .  Just like the code in my demo, I use ' product.Photo = photo.FileName;'  .

Comment: You are welcom! Glad it can help. If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.